# FTP server suddenly down

Tags: ftp, kernel, reporting

Suddenly I can not use anymore my FTP server and I get via ssh the following kernel report. I'm running on Debian 7.0 with ISPconfig3

```
kernel:[801112.466009] nf_ct_ftp: dropping packetIN= OUT=venet0 SRC=85.214.245... DST=86.56.52.... LEN=77 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54895 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=21 DPT=39376 SEQ=1843303078 ACK=714839291 WINDOW=114 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 OPT (0101080A2FBB6DB1001BDB500101050A2A9B94FA2A9B94FB)
```

I never faced this kind of error what doe it mean how to fix it?

Comment: Take this opportunity to give up FTP and switch to a much more secure protocol like sftp.

Comment: yes I will do it like so

Answer (score 0):

Try running iptables -L on the host to make sure the packet is not being dropped due to filter  rules.